# Compiling heimdal kerberos 5 implementation into a static C library for iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries, kerberos

I'm trying to compile heimdal into a static library to work with [cyrus-sasl](https://github.com/syzdek/iOSPorts) iOS ports. I was wondering if anybody has been able to make OpenLDAP for iOS work with GSSAPI authentication mechanism, or work against an Active Directory.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Wow, that would be a tremendous contribution to the eco system.